# jquery-validation how to change rule

Tags: jquery-validate

field **pesel** and **nip** are in one group. User must fill one of the two fields, then secend field is not required. But when user click submit button, function pesel or and nip are calls. how can i change rule from true to false.

For example :
when the user fills out the field correctly one (e.g. pesel), then in rules will change value nip from true to false.

my code :

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("require_from_group", function(value, element, options){
var numberRequired = options[0],
selector = options[1],
$fields = $(selector, element.form),
validOrNot = $fields.filter(function() {
    return $(this).val();
    }).length >= numberRequired,
    validator = this;
    if(!$(element).data('being_validated')) {
    $fields.data('being_validated', true).each(function(){
           validator.valid(this);
         }).data('being_validated', false);
}
if (validOrNot) {
$(selector).each(function() {
$(this).removeClass('error');
$('label.error[for='+$(this).attr('id')+']').remove();
});
}
return validOrNot;
}, jQuery.format("Jedno z pol jest wymagane."));
```

rules :

```
 submitHandler:function(form) {
         SubmittingForm();
 },
 rules: {

 numer_budynku: {
 required: true
 },
 pesel: {
    require_from_group: [1,".at_least_one"],
    pesel:true                    
    },
    nip: {
      require_from_group: [1,".at_least_one"],
      nip:true
    },
    sid: {
       required: true,
       sid:true
    }
```

Thx for help.

Comment: The `require_from_group` rule is already built into [the `additional-methods.js` file](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.12.0/additional-methods.js) so you don't need to write it out yourself.

Comment: Please do not abuse this website by posting duplicate questions.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23359301/jquery-validation-form-require-from-group

Answer (score 0):

You cannot put `nip:true` as a `key:value` pair here because it doesn't mean anything.  `nip` is not a rule.

```
nip: {  // < - name of field
    require_from_group: [1,".at_least_one"],  // <- rule declared
    nip:true    // <- meaningless, REMOVE THIS LINE
},
```

The `require_from_group` rule is already built into [the `additional-methods.js` file](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.12.0/additional-methods.js) so you don't need to write it out yourself.  Just include the file.

---

**Quote OP**:

> *"field pesel and nip are in one group. User must fill one of the two fields, then secend field is not required."*

That's what the `require_from_group` method/rule is for.

> *"But when user click submit button, function pesel or and nip are calls. how can i change rule from true to false."*

Change what rule from `true` to `false`?  The `required` rule?  You are not using the `required` rule on `nip` or `pesel` and the `require_from_group` rule *automatically* makes one fields `required`.  When one field is filled out, the other field is no longer `required`.

> *"For example : when the user fills out the field correctly one (e.g. pesel), then in rules will change value nip from true to false."*

You cannot change `nip` or `pesel` from `true` to `false` because `nip` and `pesel` are nothing that you can change from `true` to `false`.  They are not pre-defined methods/rules for this plugin.  This is the accepted format...

```
rules:  {               // <- the plugin OPTION
    myField:            // <- the field's NAME attribute
        method: param   // <- the RULE and its accepted PARAMETER(s)
    }
}
```